# GraphQL best way to filter based on grand-parent node

Tags: graphql

So the client needs a response with this structure

```
user
  |_ trophies <-- user earned trophies
        |_ trophy_count: Int <-- how many times a user earned a trophy
```

and my schema looks like:

```
type User {
  trophies: [Trophy]
}
type Trophy{
  ...
  trophy_count # <- needs the user_id to work 
}
```

Is it alright to have `trophy_count` in the `Trophy` type? How can I structure my schema to get the above query?

Answer (score 0):

### The good way

You need a type in the middle.

```
type User {
  trophies: [UserTrophy]
}
type UserTrophy {
  trophy: Trophy
  trophy_count: Int
}
type Trophy{
  # only trophy related properties
}
```

Client's query will change a bit however.

```
User{
  trophies{
    trophy{
      ...
    }
    trophy_count
}
```

### Bad solutions (to avoid)

If you must return follow the response structure above, then there are ways, but they're less maintainable/readable and can cause problems if queried in different way than you expect.

1. Pass the `user_id` as an argument to `trophy_count` (won't work when querying many users)

```
User{
  trophies{
    ...
    trophy_count(user_id: ID) # <-- filter by user_id in the resolver
}
```

2. Pass the `user_id` to the grandchildren and filter with it if available

in trophies resolver

```
return {
  ...trophy,
  user_id: parent.id
};
```

in trophy_count resolver

```
if(typeof parent.user_id == 'undefined') throw new Error("Must be queried with user type");
// continue logic ...
```

3. Never Pass the user_id in the context? Query execution happens horizontally (all users will be loaded before trophies are loaded before trophy_count is loaded) This means users will override the context and only the last user_id will actually be passed to ALL users' `trophy_count` resolver.

Feel free to suggest any other solutions.